# Is comparing pointers across allocations well-defined in Rust?

Tags: pointers, rust, language-lawyer

I have a pointer `buf: *const T` pointing to the start of an allocation of `n` elements of `T`, and I define the following check:

```rust
let in_alloc = buf <= ptr && ptr < unsafe { buf.add(n) };
```

Is it guaranteed that `in_alloc` is `true` for any `ptr` that lies in the allocation of `buf`, and `false` in any other case? We may assume that `ptr` is a valid pointer to a `T` object (so not misaligned/null/dangling), however it may or may not be from the same allocation as `buf`. Finally we may assume `T` is not zero-sized.

Answer (score 8):

Answering the title, comparing *any* two pointers is well-defined since [pointers implement `Ord`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html#impl-Ord-1).

With pointers being totally ordered, the body of the question follows easily from this. You have a set of `n` distinct pointers, starting at `buf + 0` and ending at `buf + (n - 1)`. If `ptr` is less than `buf` it can't be equal to any of them. If `ptr` is greater than `buf + (n - 1)` it also cannot be equal to them. If `ptr` is one of them, both expressions evaluate to true.

You can somewhat sidestep the issue and use `Range` instead:

```
let end = unsafe { buf.add(n) };
let in_alloc = (buf..end).contains(ptr);
```

This is often used, for example, to [check if a slice contains a pointer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.as_ptr_range).

Comment: I like this answer because it depends only on the mathematical properties implied by the pointer type's trait implementations (well, and knowing that allocations can't be _interleaved_ somehow).

Comment: _With pointers being totally ordered, the body of the question follows easily from this_ Is knowing that pointers are totally ordered enough? What guarantees that the total order is consistent with arithmetic? In C++, `std::less` gives total order for pointers, but it is not enough to implement a check that some pointer belongs to an allocated block.

Comment: _A total order on aligned pointers to T does not allow overlapping ranges_ What does «aligned pointer» mean here to guarantee this?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Actually, I thought alignment was required but even that is not needed. Specifically, `Range<*const T>` relates ordering with arithmetic. This is explicitly leveraged in documentation examples, e.g. slice [`as_ptr_range`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.as_ptr_range). More generally, Rust pointers (mostly due to LLVM) implement integer-like semantics (sometimes to a fault, like over-aggressive optimizations). There is some discussion around making this more formal in UCG WG (though, stalled afaik).

Comment: I think it's important to remember Rust doesn't have a formal spec. It's semantics are defined as a mix of documentation, what LLVM does, what it probably wants to do instead, and what people expect out of it. The integer-esque nature is an example - people (including the language implementation) will use `(x..y).contains(p)` to check for slice membership, or `p.wrapping_add` followed by a comparison to check for wrapping. When a formal spec does eventually land, it will need to provide the explicit, rather than implicit, connection. I'll edit the answer to provide some examples.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation, it is valid to produce a raw pointer one byte past the allocation *of the object the pointer points to* (so +1). Obviously you cannot dereference the pointer, but it can be used for comparisons, eg. for bounds checking in a loop.

Beyond that, it's undefined behaviour, so you're not guaranteed anything at all. In your case adding an arbitrary offset to the pointer would not be a good idea for this reason.

So, to answer more specifically, it will return the value you expect as long as `buf.add(n)` points to an address that is at most 1 byte past the allocation of the object `buf` points to.

See https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.59.0/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.offset for more details.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The answer is no, it's not guaranteed because it's undefined behaviour.

Comment: The first sentence of my question states that `buf` points to an allocation of `n` elements of `T`. Thus `buf.add(n)` is defined behavior.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I missed that part.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this code works as you would except. Comparing pointers that point to different allocations should behave as expected as implied by the [documentation of std::ptr::eq](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.eq.html).